# debian package that installs other debian packages

Tags: package-management, dpkg, packaging

I am trying to get familiar with debian packages and trying a couple of tutorials, so far [this](https://wiki.debian.org/Packaging/Intro?action=show&redirect=IntroDebianPackaging) is the only one that makes sense and also works.

So my goal is to build a package that downloads and installs a bunch of other packages first, before doing the actual job.

How do I do that? I can't find anything close to that.

Or should I put it into the `preinst` file and write a script for that?

Comment: So your package depends on package X Y and Z? Isn't that what dependencies are used for?

Comment: exactly, but when I put them into the dependencies, it just says the packages is dependent on them, it doesn't automatically install it

Answer (score 1):

You need to install your package with a package manager who understand dependencies such as `apt-get/aptitude` or `gdebi`, dpkg alone cannot do that.

```
$ gdebi your-pkg.deb
```

Comment: `sudo dpkg -i your-pkg.deb; sudo apt -f install` does same. Now, "software center" too (as gdebi)  take care of dependencies while installing a local deb package